# WPF Binding to Custom Property Not Working

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have this control to display a list of usercontrols

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="LayersList" Margin="10,284,124,0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <NaturalGroundingPlayer:LayerControl Item="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The LayerControl control contains this code

```
public partial class LayerControl : UserControl {
    public LayerItem Item { get; set; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Item",
        typeof(LayerItem),
        typeof(LayerControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public LayerControl() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        // This doesn't work because Item remains null
        MainWindow.Instance.LayersList.Items.Remove(Item);
    }
}
```

LayerItem contains this

```
[PropertyChanged.ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class LayerItem {
    public LayerType Type { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}

public enum LayerType {
    Audio,
    Video,
    Image
}
```

Problem is: The Binding is setting the Item property to null. If I change the binding to `{Binding Type}` instead of `{Binding}` (and adapt the property type accordingly), then it works. But I can't find a way to bind the whole object. What am I doing wrong?

On a side note, I tried setting `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` to a `ObservableCollection<LayerItem>` but that didn't seem to work. Adding items directly to `ItemsControl.Items` is working. Any idea why that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrectly implemented a dependency property. You should use `GetValue` and `SetValue` methods instead of creating an auto-property.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Item", typeof(LayerItem), typeof(LayerControl));

public LayerItem Item
{
    get { return (LayerItem)GetValue(ItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemProperty, value); }
}
```

P.S. You shouldn't access controls like this: `MainWindow.Instance.LayersList.Items.Remove(Item)`. You should use MVVM instead. I'm also not convinced this property is required at all. `DataContext` may be enough.

Comment: Fixing the property works. As for removing the item, DataContext returns the item, not the collection. Also, Parent is null. I didn't find a way to easily remove from the containing collection so I worked around it in that way. Would love to hear a better solution.

Comment: @EtienneCharland If the solution works, you should accept and optionally upvote it. The better solution is properly using MVVM. Look for tutorials on MVVM libraries like Caliburn.Micro or MVVM Light. There shouldn't be "Button_Click" to begin with.